# Prestashop Ajax display of assigned template variables

Tags: php, prestashop

How do I display the "assigned template variables" inside a displayajax() function (I am using prestashop 1.5.6.0).

If you go to:

```
sitedomain/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product you see the product
```

but if you go to:

```
sitedomain/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product&ajax=true you see a blank page
```

to have some output in that page I added this function in ProductController.php and it works:

```
public function displayAjax()
{
    echo "something";
}
```

How can I access all the "assigned template variables" that I see usually in the debug console of prestashop...like $combinations $groups...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assigned template variables can be returned via the following code:

```
$this->context->smarty->getTemplateVars();
```

or if you need a specific variable:

```
$this->context->smarty->getTemplateVars('combinations');
```

the method getTemplateVars() returns those variables, so you may dump it with the standard function:

```
var_dump($this->context->smarty->getTemplateVars());
```

you can add this at the displayAjax() method.

You can also call the debug window if the debug param is set (by default SMARTY_DEBUG) so url like

```
index.php?id_product=1&controller=product&ajax=1&SMARTY_DEBUG
```

with the following displayAjax():

```
public function displayAjax()
{
    $this->context->smarty->display($this->context->smarty->getDebugTemplate());
}
```

will popup the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function displayAjax()
    {
        $array= $this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['combinations'];
        foreach($array as $k => $v)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```